# PreparedStatement.executeQuery() not returning resultset

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I am using preparedStatement to insert data. I am using its executeQuery() method which returns resultSet of data just created by the Query. But I am getting exception saying you should use statement instead of preparedStatement.
Why? What should I do to get the result set? I want to fetch the id of last inserted record which is auto generated.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your actual code and the stack trace.

Comment: Why my question is down voted? what is wrong with it?

Comment: I'd say the first comment is a very good reason for the downvotes.

Comment: Its a general query. it doesn't need any sample code to be presented. If you read the question you can get the problem. I wonder some ppl just like to go on each question and downvote it to gain reputation

Comment: You don't gain rep by downvoting. On the other hand, you do gain rep by posting questions that get upvoted because they follow the guidelines of posting the information others need to help you solve your problem.

Comment: It is not always possible to post code n stack trace. Sometimes one problem can be explained only in words. If not understood, asking for code or explanation is fine but de-voting like this is demotivating.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using preparedStatement to insert data. I am using its executeQuery()

If you are using `preparedStatement` for inserting  then you should not use `executeQuery()`.

Use `executeUpdate()`

**Note**
executeUpdate() return int so if you want to check whether inserted or not then do this way

```
if(executeUpdate()>0)

{
//do some thing
}
{
else
//do somethind
}
```

Comment: `executeQuery` is perfectly reasonable to use on a `PreparedStatement`, which is a subinterface of `Statement`. It looks from your edit that you were trying to talk about `INSERT` specifically, which is a legitimate issue.

Comment: @chrylis executequery can not be used for inserting as OP is trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You get that exception because you are preparing an Insert (DML) query

to retreive your  auto generated key you should create you statement using the following Connection method

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );

ps.executeUpdate();

ResutSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
rs.first();
int generatedKey = rs.getInt(1);
```